# Solving a simple linear equation

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, linear-equation

Suppose I needed to solve the following equation,

```
ax + by = c
```

Where `a`, `b`, and `c` are known values and `x`, `y` are natural numbers between 0 and 10 (inclusively).

Other than the trivial solution of,

```
for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++)
    for (y = 0; y <= 10; y++)
         if (a * x + b * y == c)
             printf("%d %d", x, y);
```

... is there any way to find all solutions for this independent system efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, since `x` and `y` only take values between `0` and `10`, brute force algorithm maybe the best option as it takes less time to implement.

However, if you have to find all pairs of integral solution `(x, y)` in a larger range, you really should apply the right mathematical tool for tackling this problem.

You are trying to solve a linear Diophantine equation, and it is well known that integral solution exists if and only if the *greatest common divisor `d` of `a` and `b` divides `c`*.

If solution does not exist, then you are done. Otherwise, you should first apply the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) to find a paritcular solution for the equation `ax + by = d`.

And according to [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), all other integral solutions are of the form:

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/8/6/9/869734595b839cf44b8a1cb01607580f.png]

where `k` is an arbitrary integer.

But note that we are interested in the solution of `ax + by = c`, we have to scale all our pairs of `(x, y)` by a factor of `c / d`.

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid the second `for` loop by checking directly if `(c-a*x)/b` is an integer.

**EDIT**: My code is less clean than I had hoped, due to some careless oversights on my part pointed out in the comments, but it is still faster than nested `for` loops.

```
int by;
for (x = 0; x <= 10; x++) {
    by = c-a*x;                         // this is b*y

    if(b==0) {                          // check for special case of b==0
        if (by==0) {
            printf("%d and any value for y", x);
        }
    } else {                            // b!=0 case
        y  = by/b;                  
        if (by%b==0 && 0<=y && y<=10) { // is y an integer between 0 and 10?
            printf("%d %d", x, by/b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y also needs to be between 0 and 10 inclusive.

Comment: What will happen when b is 0?

Answer (score 0):

You only to loop thru x, then calculate y. (x, y) is a solution if y is integer, and between 0 and 10.

In C:

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 10; ++x) {
    double y = (double)(c - ax) / b;
    // If y is an integer, and it's between 0 and 10, then (x, y) is a solution
    BOOL isInteger = abs(floor(y) - y) < 0.001;
    if (isInteger && 0 <= y && y <= 10) {
        printf("%d %d", x, y);
    }
}
```